# ClearInterval works only one time

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

can someone help me with this code? the interval does not stop and I can not see what I'm doing wrong. when I click on the link interval stops the first time, the second time they go through all three.

```
if(location_type == 'friends'){ 
    GetReactionCount(location_type,'0',limits);
    intervals1 = setInterval(function() {
    GetReactionCount(location_type,'0',limits);
    }, 10000);
    return
        }else
    if(location_type != 'friends'){ clearInterval(intervals1); }    

    if(location_type == 'neighborhood'){
         GetReactionCount(location_type,postcode,limits);
         intervals2 = setInterval(function() {
        GetReactionCount(location_type,postcode,limits);
         }, 10000);
        return
        }else
    if(location_type != 'neighborhood'){clearInterval(intervals2); }

    if(location_type == 'city'){
         GetReactionCount(location_type,stad,limits);
         intervals3 = setInterval(function() {
        GetReactionCount(location_type,stad,limits);
         }, 10000);
        return
        }else
    if(location_type != 'city'){clearInterval(intervals3); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three possible intervals, stored in `intervals1`, `intervals2` and `intervals3`.  Each time this code is called, you stop only one of the intervals so if the second time this code is called, one of the other two intervals was running, then it will keep running and you will start another one and thus you will have two or more intervals running at that point.

If you want only one interval to ever be running, then store only one interval in one variable and stop that one interval before starting a new one.  Or, if you need all three interval variables, then make a short little function that calls `clearInterval()` on all three variables before starting a new one.

Comment: thank you for your swift reply. I'm going to try it.